# Move file upload not working in php

Tags: php

I have facing problem on file uploading this is my code for multiple files with additional input field to mention name of customer

```
        $titles=$_REQUEST['doc_title'];
        $tmp_names=$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
        $requestid=$_REQUEST['Reqno'];
        //echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; 
        //echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; die;
        $url= 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $upload_dir=str_replace('/index.php','/',$url);
        $time = time();
        $arraData=array();
        $filearray=array();
        foreach($_FILES['filename']['name'] as $key=>$value){
        $arraData[$key]['doc_title']=$titles[$key];
        $arraData[$key]['file_name']=$time.$value;
        $arraData[$key]['tmp_name']=$tmp_names[$key];
        $arraData[$key]['req_id']=$requestid;
        $pathAndName = $upload_dir."temp/Moredocument/" . $time.$value;
        $move_files=move_uploaded_file($tmp_names[$key], $pathAndName);
        }
```

i have multiple file to upload so i use foreach.
this is the $_FILES Output
for two image upload

```
Array
  (
       [filename] => Array
      (
        [name] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1472470251_example_001.pdf
                [1] => 1472462805_example_001.pdf
            )

        [type] => Array
            (
                [0] => application/pdf
                [1] => application/pdf
            )

        [tmp_name] => Array
            (
                [0] => /tmp/phpD3tfnC
                [1] => /tmp/php6w0V8W
            )

        [error] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
                [1] => 0
            )

        [size] => Array
            (
                [0] => 53915
                [1] => 53915
            )

    )

   )
```

please help where my error is.

Comment: use relative file path instead of absolute path.

Answer (score 2):

For uploading the file we need to pass absolute url of file.

Here you have used

```
 $url= 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 $upload_dir=str_replace('/index.php','/',$url);
```

This will give you the `http://` url so you can not move the file.

```
$titles=$_REQUEST['doc_title'];
$tmp_names=$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
$requestid=$_REQUEST['Reqno'];

//This is the roor url you can use __DIR__ or dirname(__FILE__)
$upload_dir= '/';

$time = time();
$arraData=array();
$filearray=array();
foreach($_FILES['filename']['name'] as $key=>$value) {

    $arraData[$key]['doc_title']=$titles[$key];
    $arraData[$key]['file_name']=$time.$value;
    $arraData[$key]['tmp_name']=$tmp_names[$key];
    $arraData[$key]['req_id']=$requestid;

    //Make sure you have created this all directories
    $pathAndName = $upload_dir."temp/Moredocument/" . $time.$value;
    $move_files=move_uploaded_file($tmp_names[$key], $pathAndName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your url for current file and what are you trying to do by using

```
$arraData[$key]['doc_title']=$titles[$key];
$arraData[$key]['file_name']=$time.$value;
$arraData[$key]['tmp_name']=$tmp_names[$key];
$arraData[$key]['req_id']=$requestid;
$pathAndName = $upload_dir."temp/Moredocument/" . $time.$value;
move_uploaded_file($tmp_names[$key], $pathAndName);
```

?

Comment: upload file what you think

Comment: Why store tmp dir in $arraData?